# QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationChanged signal not getting called for ETHERNET config changes

Tags: qt, signals, ethernet

QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationChanged()  signal is not getting called by the system when I am inserting a LAN cable with a valid IP(Ethernet interface).

It is getting called for WLAN and USB interface but  not for  ETHERNET config changes

Hope to get some pointers on this.