# qt - QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationAdded signal not working

Tags: c++, qt, qtnetwork

I have two environments (DEV and PROD). Both are linux running Connman as network manager. In my DEV environment the signal configurationAdded is working properly when I plug/unplug ethernet cable. On the other hand, in PROD env, with computer with the same hw specifications, this signal is not emitted. My question in this topic is: which it is based Qt, in particular QtNetwork, to emit this signal? What their depenedencies? I am assuming that I have any missing dependencies in PROD env by wich this is not working properly.

I have read this [QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationChanged signal not getting called for ETHERNET config changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359657/qnetworkconfigurationmanagerconfigurationchanged-signal-not-getting-called-for) but in this question the user is asking for windows, not for linux. In any case it was not resolved.

**EDIT:** Checking QNetworkConfigurationManager::capabilities, the result in DEV environment is QFlags(0x1|0x10|0x20|0x40) while in PROD env is QFlags() (empty). So this can be a problem with QtNetwork backend in PROD env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that app binary not getting right plugins path. In this case, the plugin needed is bearer. You can check this debugging with **QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::PluginsPath)**. If your path is not right, you can solve it using qt.conf file or setting paths. Both methods are specified in this [Qt documentation article](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html)